# Server Error in '/' Application. The system cannot find the file specified error after published website

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got this error after published my website.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The system cannot find the file specified
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified]

[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager) +947
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +342
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +726
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +91
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +438
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +79
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +201
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +156
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +22
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +92
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +219
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +101
   M_Project.Classes.sqlConnectionClass.CheckConnection() in C:\Users\ACER\source\repos\M Project\M Project\Classes\sqlConnectionClass.cs:17
   M_Project.Classes.UserOperations.Login(String log_email, String log_password) in C:\Users\ACER\source\repos\M Project\M Project\Classes\UserOperations.cs:57
   M_Project.log_turkish.btnLogin_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\ACER\source\repos\M Project\M Project\log_turkish.aspx.cs:23
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9796242
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +211
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +12
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1696
```

I know why this happens. I uploaded my classes but their paths are like some static path. But i don't know how to solve it.

Comment: `[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)]` Did you check the things it said to check?

Comment: I am checking now , but i think its about this part: M_Project.Classes.sqlConnectionClass.CheckConnection() in C:\Users\ACER\source\repos\M Project\M Project\Classes\sqlConnectionClass.cs:17

Comment: I am sure i write my connection right.

Comment: You might be sure, but C# is pretty sure you didn't set everything up correctly. Who do you think will win that one? :) Note; error message says Named Pipes Provider - ensure you have this provider/protocol enabled in sqlsevrer config manager

Comment: Ok im checking it thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks i solved my problem with using webdeploy while publishing my project.